# CSS not synchronized after SharePoint 2013 Migration

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Recently I Migrated SharePoint 2010 site into SharePoint 2013.
In 2010 Document Folder quick menu is looks fine

[image]

but after Migration looks like this

[image]

May be CSS not synchronized properly, and I haven't seen any issue in Logs.

Can any one suggest me on this please?

Comment: Unfortunately i am not a developer. But in every migration-project we had to completely rebuild all customizations in design and UI. This might be a good start for you: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178510.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is this problem resolved.  Can you post the solution that resolved this issue, I have just the exact problem after having migrated from 2010 to 2013.  Its CSS issue, I have registered Corev15.css and registered my own css, after=Corev15.css, that helped only the main page.  But all other pages have this issue.

Appreciate if you post your resolution.

Comment: This does not give the answer. if you want to query author of the question /answer then you must attain 50  reputations and get eligible for commenting everywhere. or else ask your own question.

Comment: Hi, I migrated entire project to SharePoint 2013 in Visual Studio 2015. 
Then Issue resolved automatically.